# rosjava_android WIFI set up in a windows based virtual box

Tags: ros, rosjava, virtualbox, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have modified the the android_tutorial_pubsub package to let it connect a roscore on PC and write a talker on PC to send message to the android phone. It works OK, but when I move to virtual box in windows 7, I hava no idea how to set up the ip for it to work. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks.
BTW, I found that the connection between the android phone and the PC can only be established when they are connected to the internet. I have tried to connect the PC and the Phone to the same router without connecting the router to the internet, the connection is not established. It only works when I connect the router to the internet. Is there a method to let it work without the internet? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31727/rosjava_android-wifi-set-up-in-a-windows-based-virtual-box/) by [alexbeta20](https://answers.ros.org/users/2130/alexbeta20/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm guessing that in the first test that you did, you were using Ubuntu, and then "moved" that Ubuntu into a VM, running on Windows as a host os?

In that setup, the Ubuntu box is most probably being NATed, so it's not in the same network as the Windows box. You would need to check de networking configuration of your virtual machine software.

Regarding the Internet connectivity requirements, there are no such requirements. It must be some other problem in your network configuration.

---

Originally posted by [tulku](https://answers.ros.org/users/2276/tulku/) with karma: 51 on 2014-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1